# KiCad: Footprint holes appear as vias

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I created a custom footprint using the S-DIP wizard. The design rules checker seems to think the pads are vias and complains about my traces being too close.

[image: red arrows from DRC]

1. What did I do wrong?
2. What can be done to fix this? Should I ignore the warnings?

Comment: Are the traces on the same net as the pads? I'm not sure what you mean by "seems to think the pads are vias"; they *are* vias. Plated through-hole pads are just big vias.

Comment: Can you post the exact warning (or error as it's red marker)? Are the pads and tracks definitely of the same net? What are your design rules?

Comment: Does your schematic show them connected?

Comment: The pin number on the footprint must match the pin number (not the pin name!) on the associated schematic symbol.

Comment: Okay, I messed with this a lot and it's working now. I believe the problem was caused by me replacing the footprint I had originally been using in the PCB but *not* in the schematic.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem was caused when I replaced the footprint only in the PCB but *not* in the schematic.